# React App Gives Error At Serving Bundled Files

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, react-context

I am building a react app that takes data from user and save it to a MongoDB database and list the data back via Node-Express backend Server.

The app works fine on dev server and it doesn't give any error at building but when Node server serving the files browser gives errors. The errors coming from Context API's state variables.

There is twelve components (almost same components) using twelve different state and all of them gives same error. To keep it simple I posted just one of them.

I tried using different bundler(Parcel.js), nothing changed.
I make a fresh create-react-app and copied my code then builded there. It didn't work either.

### The Error on Browser Console

(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lo9FKImrT-SoxulHa3vxPgRriu0laAkO/view?usp=sharing)
(https://drive.google.com/file/d/10e3zHW-a60p461y10gxPjaMHjO4E8xWt/view?usp=sharing)

### This is Line 35671

```
/*#__PURE__*/react_default.a.createElement("thead", null, /*#__PURE__*/react_default.a.createElement("tr", null, /*#__PURE__*/react_default.a.createElement("th", null, "Kamp\xFCs Ad\u0131"), /*#__PURE__*/react_default.a.createElement("th", null, "Adresi"))), /*#__PURE__*/react_default.a.createElement("tbody", null, kampus.map(function (data) {
    return /*#__PURE__*/react_default.a.createElement(DataRow, {
      key: data._id,
      data: data
    });
```

### This is the Component That Error Occurred:

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { GlobalContext } from "../../../context/GlobalContext"
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Table';
import Accordion from 'react-bootstrap/Accordion';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';
import InputGroup from 'react-bootstrap/InputGroup';



export default function Campus() {

    const { addData, kampus, getData, delData } = useContext(GlobalContext);


    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const [address, setAddress] = useState("");

    
    
    useEffect( () => {
        getData();
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, []);



    const onSubmit = async (e) => {
        
        e.preventDefault();

        const newCampus = {
            dataType: "kampus",
            name: name,
            address: address
        }

        // let form = new FormData(newCampus)
        await addData(newCampus);
        setName("");
        setAddress("");  
    }


    function DataRow({data}) {
        return (
            <tr>
                <td>{data.name}</td>
                <td>{data.address}</td>
                <td><Button style={{position: "absolute"}} variant="danger" onClick={() => delData(data._id)}>Sil</Button></td>
                <td><Button style={{position: "absolute"}} variant="info" onClick={() => updateData(data._id)}>Düzenle</Button></td>
            </tr>
        )
    }




    return (
        <>
        <Accordion className="mt-5">
        <Card>
            <Card.Header>
                <Accordion.Toggle as={Button} variant="secondary" eventKey="0" >
                    Kampüs Ekle
                </Accordion.Toggle>
            </Card.Header>
            <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
                <Form className="mt-4" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                    <Form.Group className="mr-4 ml-4">
                        <Form.Control 
                            className="mb-3" 
                            type="text" 
                            placeholder="Please Add Name"
                            value={name} onChange={ (e) =>setName(e.target.value) }
                            />
                        <Form.Control 
                            type="text" 
                            placeholder="Please Add Address"
                            value={address} onChange={ (e) =>setAddress(e.target.value) }
                            />
                    </Form.Group>
                        <Button className="mb-4 mr-4 ml-4" variant="primary" type="submit">
                           Save
                        </Button>
                </Form>
            </Accordion.Collapse>
        </Card>
        </Accordion>

// This Piece is Where the Line 35671 is correspond
            <Table className="mt-5">
               <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {kampus.map( data => ( <DataRow key={data._id} data={data}/> ))}
                </tbody>
            </Table>
        </>
    )
}
```

### Request Activity

I use Morgan to keep track of requests and this is the list of it.

```
Server is Listeing on 3010
MongoDB Connected: testcluster1-shard-00-02-bigu6.mongodb.net
GET /data-control 304 12.811 ms - -
GET /bundle.js 304 0.667 ms - -
GET /data-control 304 1.258 ms - -
GET /data-control 304 1.168 ms - -
GET /data-control 200 7.051 ms - 232
GET /data-control 304 7.551 ms - -
GET /data-control 200 7.380 ms - 232
GET /data-control 200 7.723 ms - 232
GET /data-control 200 6.813 ms - 232
GET /data-control 200 14.077 ms - 232
GET /index.js.map 200 2.149 ms - 232
GET /index.js.map 304 0.798 ms - -
```

### This is the Code of Serving Files

```
// SERVE STATIC BUILD FILE
app.use(express.static("client/build"));

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html" ))
})
```

### This is How Server Response the GET Request:

```
// IMPORT ALL MODALS
const Kampus = require("../models/Kampus");
const Bolum = require("../models/Bolum");
const Derslik = require("../models/Derslik");
const Fakulte = require("../models/Fakulte");
const OgrEleman = require("../models/OgrEleman");
const MekanKati = require("../models/MekanKati");
const MekanTuru = require("../models/MekanTuru");
const MekanOzellik = require("../models/MekanOzellik");
const CalismaTuru = require("../models/CalismaTuru");
const AkadPoz = require("../models/AkadPoz");
const IdaPoz = require("../models/IdaPoz");
const DersSuresi = require("../models/DersSuresi");

exports.getData = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const kampus = await Kampus.find();
        const bolum = await Bolum.find();
        const derslik = await Derslik.find();
        const fakulte = await Fakulte.find();
        const ogrEleman = await OgrEleman.find();
        const mekanKati = await MekanKati.find();
        const mekanTuru = await MekanTuru.find();
        const mekanOzellik = await MekanOzellik.find();
        const calismaTuru = await CalismaTuru.find();
        const akadPoz = await AkadPoz.find();
        const idaPoz = await IdaPoz.find();
        const dersSuresi = await DersSuresi.find();

      return res.status(200).json({
          success: true,
          kampus: kampus,
          bolum: bolum,
          derslik: derslik,
          fakulte: fakulte,
          ogrEleman: ogrEleman,
          mekanKati: mekanKati,
          mekanTuru: mekanTuru,
          mekanOzellik: mekanOzellik,
          calismaTuru: calismaTuru,
          akadPoz: akadPoz,
          idaPoz: idaPoz,
          dersSuresi: dersSuresi
      });
    }
    catch (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({
            success: false,
            error: "Server Error"
        });
    }
}
```

### This is Global Context:

```
import React, {createContext, useReducer} from 'react';
import AppReducer from './AppReducer';
import initalState from "./State";
import axios from "axios";

export const GlobalContext = createContext(initalState);

export function GlobalProvider({ children }) {

    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(AppReducer, initalState);

    // ACTIONS

    // GET DATA

    async function getData () {
        try {
            const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:3010/data-control");

            dispatch({
                type: "get-data",
                payload: res.data
            });
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    }

    // ADD DATA

    async function addData (data) {
        try {
            const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3010/data-control', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
            });

            let newRes = await res.json()

            dispatch({
            type: "add-data",
            payload: newRes.data,
            dataType: newRes.case
            })
        
        } 
        catch (err) {
            console.log(err.message)
        }
    }

    
    // DELETE DATA

    async function delData (id) {
        try {
            await axios.delete(`http://localhost:3010/data-control/${id}`);

            dispatch({
                type: "del-data",
                payload: id
            })
        } 
        catch (err) {
            console.log(err.message)
        }
    }
   

   return(
        <GlobalContext.Provider value={{
            kampus: state.kampus,
            fakulte: state.fakulte,
            bolum: state.bolum,
            ogrEleman: state.ogrEleman,
            derslik: state.derslik,
            ders: state.ders,
            mekanKati: state.mekanKati,
            mekanTuru: state.mekanTuru,
            mekanOzellik: state.mekanOzellik,
            calismaTuru: state.calismaTuru,
            akadPoz: state.akadPoz,
            idaPoz: state.idaPoz,
            dersSuresi: state.dersSuresi,
            delData,
            addData,
            getData,
        }}>
            {children}
        </GlobalContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

### My State File:

```
const state = {
    kampus:[],
    bolum:[],
    derslik:[],
    fakulte:[],
    ogrEleman:[],
    ders: [],
    mekanKati: [],
    mekanTuru: [],
    mekanOzellik: [],
    calismaTuru: [],
    akadPoz: [],
    idaPoz: [],
    dersSuresi: []
}

export default state;
```

### This is How App Reducer Handles the State:

```
export default (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {

        case "get-data":

            return {
                ...state,
                kampus: action.payload.kampus,
                bolum: action.payload.bolum,
                derslik: action.payload.derslik,
                fakulte: action.payload.fakulte,
                ogrEleman: action.payload.ogrEleman,
                akadPoz: action.payload.akadPoz,
                idaPoz: action.payload.idaPoz,
                calismaTuru: action.payload.calismaTuru,
                mekanKati: action.payload.mekanKati,
                mekanTuru: action.payload.mekanTuru,
                mekanOzellik: action.payload.mekanOzellik,
                dersSuresi: action.payload.dersSuresi,
            }
    }
}
```

### Webpack Config:

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

const rules = [
    {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
            loader: "babel-loader"
        }
    },

    {
        test: /\.css$/,
        // exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
    },

    {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader"
          }
        ]
      }
]

module.exports = {
    entry: path.join(__dirname, "src", "index.js"),
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./build")
    },

    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
    },

    optimization: {
        minimize: false
    },

    module: {rules},
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "./public/index.html",
            filename: "./index.html"
        })
    ]
}
```

### Babel:

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
    "plugins": [
        ["@babel/transform-runtime"]
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hi Bugra :) So you get an 200 response right ? I am not sure but I think the server is returning an empty json. One more thing, are you able to insert the data in the database ?

Comment: For the server response I suggest you to hold the json in a variable and check if it's not empty or check you have at least one variable (kampus), you may want to return an 404 then. When the server respond 200 (success) you may not need to have it in your json.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will do:

```
  //I removed the success: true
  let jobj = {
      kampus: kampus,
      bolum: bolum,
      derslik: derslik,
      fakulte: fakulte,
      ogrEleman: ogrEleman,
      mekanKati: mekanKati,
      mekanTuru: mekanTuru,
      mekanOzellik: mekanOzellik,
      calismaTuru: calismaTuru,
      akadPoz: akadPoz,
      idaPoz: idaPoz,
      dersSuresi: dersSuresi
  };

  JSON.stringify(jobj);

  //some check up here (maybe you will send a 404 response)
  ...

  //then you send the json
  return res.status(200).json(jobj);
```